# Issues with facebook authentication getuser() returning 0

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have an issue with Facebook website authentication - in particular getuser() returning 0...

Using the Facebook API the following code registers a user with Facebook. I know that the authentication with FB is working because when I log into FB as a user, it shows that the user has given the website app access to the FB account.

The below code is what I am using to access the FB account once the user has registered the website with FB.

```
session_start();

$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxx...',
    'secret' => 'xxxx...',//);
    'cookie' => true,);

$fb = new Facebook($config);
$user = $fb->getUser();
```

Essentially what is happening is that the $fb object is not returning values once the user has registered the app on facebook...

A lot of other people have had a similar issue judging by the similar questions from other users. I have spent the past few days working through the recommended solutions offered by other users but with no luck...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong??

Ian

Comment: use `try-catch` on the `$fb->getUser()` and see if you can catch the exception

Comment: Check the cookies your browser is receiving in the HTTP responses (Net-panel on Firebug f.e.) – and see if your browser accepts them.

Comment: yep it appears to be accepting two elements fc and PHPSESSID so looks like cookies are working

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your registered user is not registered.

Try with a `try/catch` block to see what happened:

```
$fb = new Facebook($config);
$user = $fb->getUser();
try {
    $user_profile = $fb->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: have tried FacebookApiException... not returning anything... I know that the user can register for the site because it comes up as an app in their FB account, when they are redirected back to the page to login, it returns nothing...

Comment: can you change to cookie false ?

Comment: Mihai, I have tried setting cookies to false and also removing it all together but with no luck... Am running on a localhost. Not sure if that is impacting it. I have a virtual domain on the host that maps to what I have in the App config on FB... ie identical domain to what I will be using in production. So in theory this should not be an issue...

Comment: thanks mihai, this is what i thought... hmmm it has me completely stumped... Clearly the user is not being logged in otherwise it would return the user details in the object... Do you know if there is there anything I can do in the FB environment to debug (eg logging of user logins etc)??

Comment: No, I don't know nothing about that, but my tests work without any problem ... with the exact code above.

Comment: Using try/catch here makes no sense, since the getUser method does not throw any exceptions …

Comment: `$facebook->api` does throw exception ... @IanJF try with this

Comment: Mihai Iorga are you saying apply $fb->api as the test for the try/catch?? ie try {
    $user = $fb->api;
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}

Comment: got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dwabble/src/facebook/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt CApath: none thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dwabble/src/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 820

Comment: Then you forgot to add certificates, Facebook SDK comes with 1 certificate `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`, download it from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Comment: think you may have found the issue... looks like it is now logging in... Thank you so much Mihai... I really do appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your page is built. Have you provided a login button on your page? If not I think you are confusing your situation with offline access to accounts, which is an entirely different case altogether.

If you have provided your users an option to login on your page , how are you building your login button (or other element)?

You need to generate the login url with the facebook object. For a simple button for instance the login url should be generated like this (assuming this is happening in a PHP file inside a <?php ?> block):

```
session_start();
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxx...',
    'secret' => 'xxxx...',//);
    'cookie' => true /* not sure if the cookie parameter is necessary */ );

$fb = new Facebook($config);

echo '<a href="' . $fb->getLoginUrl() . '"><button>Login</button></a>';
```

This will generate the necessary parameters for authentication and redirection of the facebook authentication server so that you don't have to worry about how it's processed.

Not sure if this was your problem but if so glad to be of service.